# Use PHP to change the order of elements

Tags: php

I have some markup like so:

```
<div class="list">

    <article> content... </article>
    <article> content... </article>
    <article> content... </article>
    <article> content... </article>
    <article> content... </article>

</div>
```

What I want to do is make the order of what these articles appears on the page random. What would be the best and easiest way to do this?

I thought about doing some sort of length count and storing it in an array and then spitting them back out again in a random order. e.g.

```
$numbers = range(1, 20);
shuffle($numbers);
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    echo "$number ";
}
```

Can anyone offer ideas etc? Thanks

**NOTE: These are not coming from a database!**

Comment: What is your data source then? Are they already in an array or do you need to parse the HTML source?

Comment: It's just HTML on the page as you see above.

Comment: I would start with looking at DOMDocument to parse the HTML

Comment: The `range()` call is not needed. `shuffle()` randomizes any array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Every day I'm shuffling!](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)

But yeah, having your contents in a PHP array, then displaying them all through a little `foreach` would be fine. Example :

```
$content = array('content1', 'content2', 'content3');
shuffle($content);
echo '<div>';
foreach($content as $value) {
  echo '<article>', $value, '</article>';
}
echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your elements are stored in an array you can use the `shuffle()` function:

```
$a = array('a', 'b', 'c');
shuffle($a);
```

This leads to a random sort of `$a`.

Comment: But you can't assume that, since he said that's what he's **thinking** of doing. He's asking for a better solution...

Comment: He added that code segment later. The original post didn't contain that part.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with something slightly more complicated than echoing out chunks of HTML from a database, you want to look at the [`DOMDocument` class](http://il.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). It will assist you with manipulating the HTML (a.k.a. the DOM) in any way you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

You could use DOMDocument.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadXML($html);

$articles = $dom->getElementsByTagName('article');

$articlesShuffled = array();

// What is a good way in PHP to turn an array-like object into a real array?    
foreach($articles as $article) {
           $articlesShuffled[] = $article;
}

shuffle($articlesShuffled);

foreach($articlesShuffled as $article) {
        $article->parentNode->appendChild($article);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/NqMt0K).

I treated the input as XML because the `loadHTML()` method complains about the `article` element. I guess you'd need to supply a HTML5 doctype (or tell DOMDocument the schema) for that to work.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the DOM class: http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php and a DFS to mix the first level of the tree.